# Unable to combine date and time in c# mvc model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a model like this.

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true), Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true), Display(Name = "Start Time")]
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
```

I want to combine them into 1 variable.

I have searched that the code should be like this.

```
newDateTime = date.Date + time.TimeOfDay;
```

But I tried,

```
    [Display(Name = "Start Time")]
    public DateTime? FullStartTime
    {
        get
        {
            return StartDate.Date + StartTime.TimeOfDay;
            //or return StartDate + StartTime;
        }
    }
```

Neither of them work. Where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you got any error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to create a `DateTime` object from two different `DateTime`, you have to create a new `DateTime` object and use its contructor following way:

```
newDateTime = new DateTime(date.Date.Year, date.Date.Month,date.Date.Year,time.Hour,time.Minutes,time.Second);
```

Comment: I cannot access anything  in StartDate and StartTime.
http://i.imgur.com/B3Q6Jr5.png

Comment: It is nullable so do: ``StartDate.Value.Date.Year`` and you have to check for null as well before using ``Value`` otherwise Null reference exception will come

Answer (score 0):

You should to check if `StartDate` and `StartTime` is not null (Your properties is nullable types)

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true), Display(Name = "Start Date")]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true), Display(Name = "Start Time")]
public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Start Time")]
public DateTime? FullStartTime
{
    get
    {
        if(StartDate == null || StartTime == null) return null;

        return StartDate.Value.Date + StartTime.Value.TimeOfDay;
        //or return StartDate + StartTime;
    }
}
```